# signal handling on background process and file output

Tags: c, unix, signals, fork

I have been considering the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

FILE* file;

void signal_handler(int _signal) {
    switch(_signal){
        case SIGTERM:
            fprintf(file, "Ouch, the Daemon Child was killed!\n");
            fflush(file);
            abort();
        default:
            fprintf(file, "So what?!\n");
            fflush(file);
    }
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid != 0) {
        // parent
        waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG); // daemonize the child
    } else {
        // child
        signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
        file = fopen("daemon.txt", "w");
        while(1) {
            sleep(1);
            fprintf(file, "Daemon child is alive.\n");
            fflush(file);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I expected I could find at the end of `daemon.txt` the string `Ouch, the Daemon Child was killed!`, after `sudo kill -KILL` . However, this is not the case. Where is my fault?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, "Ouch, the Daemon Child was killed!\n" should be printed when the process receives SIGTERM. However, you send SIGKILL towards it. What were you expecting?

Comment: where can I find the complete list for kill's signals? I referred to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_signal.htm but no SIGKILL there

Comment: Signals are OS-dependent. As a starting point, see this : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html but it's best if you refer to your operating system's `signal.h` file.

Comment: Or read the man page for `signal(3)` or `signal(7)` depending on the OS.

Comment: In a shell, `kill -l` will list signal names/numbers.

Comment: On a side note: don't call `stdio` functions from signal handlers.

Comment: @SatoKatsura why?

Comment: For the record: I did ***not*** vote to migrate this question; I voted to close as "a problem that went away when a typo was fixed".

Comment: @Fabio They aren't reentrant.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be catching `SIGTERM`, and then sending `SIGKILL`, which you do not have a handler for.  You will probably see your expected output if you use `kill -TERM $pid` rather than `kill -KILL`.